# Running query is returning previous filled cells as null

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

When I run a query that just brings back the columns, it works as intended i.e.

```
SELECT 
 start_station_name,
 start_station_id,
 end_station_name,
 end_station_id,
FROM `casestudycyclistic-359515.DIvvyData.November2021` LIMIT 1000
```

This gives the proper values of the street names and IDs of the stations.

However when I run a query intended to add two columns to the table, the result nulls those values.

```
CREATE TABLE `casestudycyclistic-359515.DIvvyData.November2021rev2` AS (
 SELECT
 ride_id,
 ended_at,
 (ended_at - started_at) AS ride_length,
 EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM ended_at) AS WEEKDAY,
started_at,
start_station_name,
start_station_id
end_station_name,
end_station_id,
start_lat,
start_lng,
end_lat,
end_lng,
member_casual,
FROM
`casestudycyclistic-359515.DIvvyData.November2021`
```

)

Most of but not all the values in those four columns return as null. What have I done wrong here?

Comment: First make sure you are comparing the same rows. You only select 1000 rows, but you don't have an `ORDER BY`, so you can't predict which rows you select.

Comment: Adding to above statement from @honeybadger, a select statement in SQL does not guarantee an ordering of result set rows upon return without an ORDER BY clause.